# Nothing fetching content with server

Tags: php, html, css, mysql

Hosting company updated servers or added new patchs can't get a straight answer.

I updated code looked online and stuck.  Tried to have hosting check with server and company keeps coming back and saying its the code.

Don't know what else to do and help would be appreciated.

```
<?
include_once("mysql_nitrousgarage.inc");

$clean_url = substr($PHP_SELF,1);
$clean_url = substr($clean_url,0,-5);
$q = "SELECT * from NG_product where active='Y' and 
clean_url='$clean_url'";

$results = mysql_query($q);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($results);
$product_id = $row["product_id"];
$product_name = $row["product_name"];
$sku = $row["sku"];
$description = $row["description"];
$meta_title = $row["meta_title"];
$meta_description = $row["meta_description"];

$magiczoomplus = "Y";
include_once("topnav.inc") 
?>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-   
scale=1.0">

<meta name="viewport" content="width=400, user-scalable=no">
<script type="text/javascript"   
src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-   
52f96c9761c7b0cb" async="async"></script>

<div class="box-border">
<a href="index.php">Home</a> &rsaquo; 
<?
if ($saved_category_id || !$saved_brand_id)
{
if ($saved_category_id)
        $q = "SELECT * from NG_category where     
category_id='$saved_category_id'";
else
        $q = "SELECT * from NG_product_category as pc, NG_category    
as c where pc.product_id='$product_id' and    
pc.category_id=c.category_id order by c.order_placement limit 1";
$results = mysql_nitrousgarage.inc($q);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($results);
$category_id = $row["category_id"];
$category = $row["category"];
$category_clean_url = $row["clean_url"];
echo "<a href='$category_clean_url'>$category Wheels</a>";
}
else
{
$q = "SELECT * from NG_brand where brand_id='$saved_brand_id'";
$results = mysql_query($q);
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($results);
$brand_id = $row["brand_id"];
$brand = $row["brand"];
$brand_clean_url = $row["clean_url"];
echo "<a href='$brand_clean_url'>$brand Wheels</a>";
}
?>
 &rsaquo; <?echo $product_name?>
 <div class="page-numbers">
    <a href="<?echo $category_clean_url?>">&lsaquo; Back to <?echo    
$category?> Wheels</a>
</div>
</div>

<div class="space20"></div>

<?
$image_id_arr = array();
$q1 = "SELECT * from NG_finish as f, NG_product_finish as pf, NG_finish_image as fi where f.active='Y' and f.finish_id=pf.finish_id and pf.active='Y' and pf.product_id='$product_id' and pf.product_finish_id=fi.product_finish_id and fi.active='Y' order by f.order_placement,fi.order_placement";
$r1 = mysql_query($q1);
while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($r1))
{
        $image_id = $row1["image_id"];
    $product_finish_name = $row1["product_finish_name"];
        if (!$main_image)
    {
                $main_image = "finish-$image_id.jpg";
        $selected_finish = $product_finish_name;
    }
        $image_id_arr[] = $image_id;
    $product_finish_name_arr[] = $product_finish_name;
}
?>

<div class="simpletable">
<div class="row">
    <div class="simplecell details-cll1">
        <div id="m-container">
            <img class="maxwidth" id="m-img" src="productphotos/<?echo $main_image?>" width=488>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="simplecell" style="width: 3%"></div>
    <div class="simplecell details-cll2">

<!--<div class="details-share">
            <a href="#"><img src="images/facebook.jpg"></a>
            <br class="nomobile">
            <a href="#"><img src="images/twitter.jpg"></a>
            <br class="nomobile">
            <a href="#"><img src="images/mail.jpg"></a>
            <br class="nomobile">
            <a href="#"><img src="images/plus.jpg"></a>
</div>-->

<span class="details-title"><?echo $product_name?></span>

        <div class="style-number">Style: <?echo $sku?></div>
<div class="selected-finish">Selected Finish: <span id=finish_layer>

<?echo $selected_finish?></span>
</div>

        <div class="space30"></div>
        <br>
        <div class="simpleinline">
            <div class="like-wheel">Like this Wheel?</div>
            <div class="more-info-via">GET MORE INFO VIA</div>
        </div>
        <div class="simpleinline">
            &nbsp; <a class="like-buttons" href="wheel-inquiry.php?product_id=<?echo $product_id?>&contact=C">CALL/TEXT</a> &nbsp; <a class="like-buttons" href="wheel-inquiry.php?product_id=<?echo $product_id?>&contact=E">EMAIL</a>
        </div>

        <div class="space50 nomobile"></div>
        <div class="space30"></div>
<?
while(list($k,$v) = each($image_id_arr))
{
    $product_finish_name = $product_finish_name_arr[$k];
    echo "<a href=\"javascript:void(0);\" onClick=\"pick('productphotos/finish-$v.jpg');document.getElementById('finish_layer').innerHTML='$product_finish_name';\"><img class='maxwidth' src='productphotos/finish-$v.jpg' width=145></a>";
}
?>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="space20"></div>

<div class="box-border">
    <div class="simpletable">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="simplecell product-desc">
<?echo $description?>
        </div>
        <!--<div class="simplecell price-notshow">
            <b>Why are prices not shown?</b>
            <br><br>
            Many of our customers frequently ask us why are the prices not show.
        </div>-->
    </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="space20"></div>
<?
$q = "SELECT * FROM NG_gallery WHERE active='y' and product_id='$product_id' ORDER BY featured desc, orderplacement limit 3";
$results = mysql_query($q);
if (mysql_num_rows($results) > 0) { ?>

<b><?echo $product_name?></b> Vehicle Gallery

<div class="page-numbers">
    CLICK IMAGE TO <b>ENLARGE | <a href="vehiclegallery.php?category_id=<?echo $category_id?>&product_id=<?echo $product_id?>">VIEW MORE</a></b>
</div>

<?
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($results))
{
    $gallery_id = $row["gallery_id"];
    $gallery_title = $row["gallery_title"];
    $gallery_pics .= "<a href='productphotos/gallery_$gallery_id-l.jpg' class='MagicZoomPlus' id='Zoomer$gallery_id' rel='zoom-position: inner; zoom-width:400px;zoom-height:500px;' title='$gallery_title'><img class='maxwidth' src='productphotos/gallery_$gallery_id-l.jpg' width=380 border=0></a>";
}
?>


<div class="details-img-container">
<nobr>
<?echo $gallery_pics?>
</nobr>
</div>
<div class="details-img-container2">
<?echo $gallery_pics?>
</div>

<?}?>

<? include_once("footer.inc") ?>
```

Before updates of server page was working fine.

Comment: It is most likely that the update was an upgrade. Looking at your code it means that you have to upgrade your mysql(i.e to mysqli)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why shouldn't I use mysql\_\* functions in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Comment: do a `phpversion()` to test what version of php they have - the `mysql` api will not work ( doesn't exist ) for php 7+

Comment: This looks like *very* old code. As others have mentioned, the `mysql_*` functions no longer exist, short open tags (`<?` instead of `<?php`) are disabled by default and the `$PHP_SELF` variable was deprecated in PHP 4.2.0 (it required `register_globals` to be on, which hasn't been possible since PHP 5.4.0). I'm also confused by the line `$results = mysql_nitrousgarage.inc($q);` -- I'm not familiar with nitrous garage but that `.` is a string concatenator and would invalidate `$result` for use in `mysql_fetch_array` on the next line. This whole code is in need of a rewrite.

Comment: thanks I'm learning php and trying to help out with this site.  Will look at info here and move to rewrite page.